# подключить open server к базе данных в mySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. Сделал базу данных через mySQL workbench. Задача подключиться к open server. Но возникает такая ошибка access denied for user root localhost using password: yes. Сразу скажу что в open server ip и port совпадают с тем что я ввожу при подключении в workbench. Не могу найти в интернете решение которое было подошло мне. Может кто-то знает как исправить это. Буду благодарен)

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо разобраться с паролем. Ругается на него.

Плюс считаю [данное руководство c хабра](https://habr.com/en/post/175985/) вам поможет.

Чуть ниже в статье описано подключение к **OpenServer**.

Comment: такая проблема то что правильный пароль я помню, и у меня получается подключиться с этим паролем к mySQL server. Но с этим паролем не получается подключиться к Open server. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: ```@ArsBryant``` предлагаю два варианта ещё:

1) Создать MysSQL Connection с параметрами: localhost, порт 3306, юзер root, без пароля.
 или 
2) выбрать там же готовый тип подключения local и с ним подключиться. 

Отпишитесь, найдём ещё варианты, если эти не сработают

Comment: Connection Method выбрать Local в MySQL Connections в настройках